# Weird line-break on special character

Tags: html, css, fonts

#### The problem

I recently discovered an encoding problem in my backend for when calculating the initials of a user when the first letter is germanic letter (e.g `Ö` and `Ä`). Those letters couldn't be parsed and ended up being a question-mark.

But what I also discovered is a rather peculiar behavior (and the reason I seek advise) in my markup that simply makes no sense to me whatsoever.

I've replicated simplified example below:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 260px;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}

.avatar {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  align-self: auto;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar span {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="avatar">
      <span>?N</span>
    </div>
    <h4>Örjan Norberg</h4>
    <span>orjan@example.com</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatar">
      <span>II</span>
    </div>
    <h4>Isaac Ibarra</h4>
    <span>isaac@example.com</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatar">
      <span>WW</span>
    </div>
    <h4>Wyatt Williams</h4>
    <span>wyatt@example.com</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You'll see that "Örjans" initials are `?N`, but also that the "N" is being pushed down to the next line. This doesn't seem to be related to the avatar width because I tried with both long and short initials.

In fact, even if I put `WWWWW` or something else ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB7f6.png)) that overflows the avatar, there is no line-break which is as expected. I also tried other special characters, such as `&` and `%`, but those behave just as any other character or letter.

---

#### Question

What causes this behavior when using the question-mark specifically? Is it somehow related to the font ([Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)) or is it my css?

Also, (see pics below) how come this happens when the question-mark is followed by a letter, but not when the order is reversed (letter first) or when followed by another question-mark?

[image]

What's going on here??

---

**EDIT 1:** Using OSX/Chrome.v59, though can replicate in Windows7/IE11

**EDIT 2:** Apparently the `—` character [also causes this behavior](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f05g05st/4/) (thanks to @MrLister for finding this)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there is no line break for me (FF/Debian). Anyway, I would expect that what you see isn't simply a question mark, but due to encoding issues, there are control characters that bring the line break about.

Comment: @domdom, oh that's interesting, thanks. I'll update my post to provide OS/Browser as well.

Comment: @MrLister, infinite. See my post where I linked a picture.

Comment: Interesting. It seems to be related to the font. If you change the font-family to arial this error does not persist. The issue also vanishes when `position: absolute;` is removed from `.avatar span`.The question mark is treated as different dom object (somehow) which you can see in the developer tools and lead to the undesired line break.

Comment: @NicoO, indeed, I've noticed that the problem vanishes when you do those changes. While that's a great solution, I'm more interested in the cause of this than actually solving the issue. Also, I cannot see the line-break in the dev-tools. I only see `<span>?N</span>`. Can you provide a screenshot of your dev-tools where the line-break is visible? Thanks again!

Comment: @domdom If you take the snippet and increase the span's font size, you will see it happen to you too.

Comment: Sorry, That was a rendition error in the dev tools.  Some parts of the dom were still selected. Non the less here is a even more minified version of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/f05g05st/2/ if you remove the transform and the left it also works: https://jsfiddle.net/f05g05st/3/

Comment: @NicoO It also doesn't have anything to do with the font, only with the character. More minified example: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f05g05st/4/

Comment: @MrLister this must be the reason why they used the question mark for questions in the first place.

Comment: Step 1: *is everything using unicode*. E.g. is your database using true unicode (utf8mb4 for instance), is your connection to it set to talk in unicode, is the server set to *serve* unicode, and does your HTML markup contain `<meta charset="utf-8">`? If so, and the issue is truly just related to "word breaks between ? and something else", then your backend and even content is irrelevant and you should reduce this question to a much smaller description and [mcve].

Comment: also note that moving things left by 50% (which your CSS does) ignores the fact that the text itself also has a width, and so the browser simply inserts a wordbreak where it can due to the fact that your CSS does not leave enough room for both letters. Change the left positioning to 47% and suddenly everything fits in the browsers that present the content "wrong" (but actually correct) at 50%.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My last fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f05g05st/4/ is pretty much as mcve as you can get. And fiddles use UTF-8, so that can't be the problem either. Also, I'm not sure why you think that putting an absolutely positioned element on left:47% instead of left:50% would change anything.

Comment: Simple: it *should* be `50% - whateverWidthTheTextIs/2` but CSS can't do that, so something like 47%, **in this particular case** would work, but the resolution is "don't use the absolute + left + translate" because there is literally no reason to expect that does anything useful, based on what the CSS spec says each of those properties do. Just `text-align:center` the div content, because that's what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

What you see happening is that the bounding client rectangle for the combination `?N` is too wide to fit without overflow, and so the browser does whatever it should do when it sees overflow, based on default rules and CSS overrides. Part of the reason is that the `translate` and `scale` transforms do *not* reposition elements, they only **draw** them somewhere else, so your transform does not counteract your absolute positioning. Have a look at http://jsbin.com/gujafokiwe/edit?html,css,output and notice that as far as the DOM is concerned that span is *still in its original position*, we've only told CSS to draw it somewhere else.

When the browser sees `?N` (and specifically: some browsers. Not all of them) it might see that it needs to break the line based on the bounding client rect dimensions. However, browsers are free to pick their rules for when and how to break text sequences (CSS [does not specify](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#soft-wrap-opportunity) which rules *must* be used, only that for unicode content outside of CJK it is advisable to use http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-37.html) and while your example works fine in my Firefox, not breaking the text at all, my Chrome does see overflow, and does try to break up the sequence(s) as best as it knows how to.

Unfortunately, the only *true* answer on why it does that is in the code for the text render engine - that's either in Blink, or in Webkit, both of which are (mostly) open source and so unless you happen to get the eyes of the person or people who implemented it on this question, you're going to have to seek them out rather than hope they browser Stackoverflow and find your question: your best bet is to read through http://www.chromium.org/blink#participating and then post this question to their dev mailing list.

(Solutions for your problem are varied: remove the `.avatar span` rule and just `text-align: center` the parent div, or even better: use flexbox rules)

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: just because you don't like it, doesn't make it not the right answer.

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question. *"What causes this behavior when using the question-mark specifically?"* As I've told others in comments, I have already solved the *issue* but I am curious as to why this happened to some characters specifically. Sorry for not commenting earlier, I only had my phone at the time.

Comment: Short answer is "it doesn't": you've also discovered it happened with the em dash, and really it happens with *any* character combination that is wide enough to cause overflow with your 50%/50% rules. I've edited the answer to only really focus on "why it happens" but you won't like the answer: the only true answer is going to come from reading the Blink/Webkit source code that handles text breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The ? in the first span is a word-break opportunity; after all, the N is the start of a word. This doesn't happen in the other spans, since those contain a whole word each only. So what you should do is apply `white-space: nowrap` to the span, so that it no longer wraps.

Edit: while this is not the explanation to what's actually happening - it doesn't happen with most other non-word characters, so "word boundary" is not the whole of the story; see comments - it still provides a practical workaround, so I'm leaving this up.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 260px;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}

.avatar {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  align-self: auto;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar span {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="avatar">
      <span>?N</span>
    </div>
    <h4>Örjan Norberg</h4>
    <span>orjan@example.com</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatar">
      <span>II</span>
    </div>
    <h4>Isaac Ibarra</h4>
    <span>isaac@example.com</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatar">
      <span>WW</span>
    </div>
    <h4>Wyatt Williams</h4>
    <span>wyatt@example.com</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"The ? in the span is a word-break opportunity"* - true, but so is `!` and `.` but those don't cause a word-break. Your code solves the *issue* but doesn't answer my question. Thanks though :)

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry I didn't read the other comments while I was typing my answer, but it does seem to happen only with question marks. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, friend

Comment: I still think this answer is correct. If you remove the left and transform properties of `.avatar span` it also works. Maybe the problem with the question mark in this case is, that it happens to be the wides "word-break opportunity" in some dense case of sub-pixel-font-rendering-magic

Comment: @NicoO, I really appreciate your effort you've shown in this issue, but I'm not looking for a *solution* to the problem, but an *explanation* to the behavior. This answer *solves* the problem, but doesn't explain it. That's what I need. :)

Comment: The same happens with characters like em dashes, but not with other wide chars like percent signs. So, still not sure what's going on and this is not really the answer to the question, only a workaround.